# Upgrading memory in a laptop

Tags: memory, hardware-selection

I'm a bit confused about all the memory types and various bus frequencies of modern consumer PCs. Requesting expert help on the subject.

So far I'm confident that:

- I have an Asus X51L laptop with an unknown set of configuration options.
- The CPU in there supports PAE, so I still have a chance to extend the memory beyond 3GiB; and the upper limit of the system is 8GiB. (?)
- The laptop has two SODIMM slots, one of which is occupied by a 2GiB bank, and the other one is empty.
- `dmidecode` and `lshw` tools consistently state **533 Mhz** frequency of the bank.

The last one confuses me the most. I failed to find out characteristics of the northbridge in this laptop, and still can't figure out what DDR2 to seek for. Is it **DDR2-1066**? Or, rather, PC2-8500/PC2-8600? Wouldn't a **DDR2-800** bank harm the system's performance?

Which kind of modules should I look up in stores?

---

**Update:**
I have bought a 2 GiB DDR2-800 SODIMM, and it seams that the system can't handle 4 GiB of memory. When installed by itself in either slot, both new and old bank (which btw happens to be marked **GDDR2-677**) work just perfectly; i.e. any configuration resulting in 2 GiB works. When both banks are installed though (totalling in 4 GiB), the `memcheck86` tool produces horrible artifacts and crashes, and system reboots; an Ubuntu system can be started and even logged into a Unity session, but the system reboots too in this case from even a minor RAM load.

So it's pretty obvious to me now that this laptop doesn't support 4 GiB of RAM or more.

Answer (score 1):

The best advice I can give you is to download the [Crucial Memory Advisor](http://www.crucial.com/systemscanner/index.aspx).
You don't have to buy your RAM from Crucial (though I would certainly recommend them), but this tool will tell you exactly what kind of RAM you should be buying, and what your best upgrade options are.

Also if you *DO* purchase your RAM through Crucial using their memory advisor tool and it doesn't work I believe they still give you a full refund.

---

On the off-chance you're running Linux/BSD/something where the Crucial tool isn't an option, you can use `dmidecode` (if installed) to get similar information. It will provide you output like this:

```
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0028
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 1024 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK0
    Type: Other
    Type Detail: Other
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: Manufacturer00
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: AssetTagNum0
    Part Number:                   
    Rank: Unknown
```

Which you can then match up to memory specs from manufacturers/retailers.

Comment: Unfortunately they don't seem to have a Linux version of the tool, so this doesn't quite solve the problem for me. I'll try to use their on-site support materials though.

Comment: @ulidtko Specifying your OS in the tags often gets you better (OS-Specific) advice :-)

Comment: @voteraq7, well, this is pretty much a hardware question...

Comment: update: yes, I've used `dmidecode` tool, it shows me DDR2 memory bank with a line  **Speed: 533 MHz (1.9 ns)**. Does that mean that I should go for **DDR2-1066**? It's barely available in the stores.

Comment: Also, the `crucial.com` website just has proven to me to be unreliable: on [this link](http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=X51L) it says: "Your X51L System Specs... *Each memory slot can hold DDR2 PC2-5300, DDR2 PC2-6400 with a maximum of 1GB per slot.*", which is straight incorrect insofar my system has 2GiB in one slot.

Comment: @ulidtko: I believe this is correct. Your particular X51L has 1GB onboard. You have a 1GB module, for a total of 2GB. Each slot can hold 1GB.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz what do you mean by "onboard"? I'm pretty sure that it is a single 2GiB module. Consider also [this hardware report](http://pastebin.com/yTuWSXcV), it clearly shows no fancy 1GiB splits.

Comment: Hmm, that does seem to say you have a 2GB module and an empty slot. Are you 100% sure it's an X51L?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, yes. 2GB module and an empty slot. X51L, 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading your laptop should start with the RAM module and the processor itself, although it's more likely for a user to change the RAM module for a better one rather than the core of the gadget.